# The data i am inserting is inserted into the table in db but not displaying on the ui

Tags: java, jdbc, crud

Error on clicking the edit or delete button on ui

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [com.ntt.web.EmployeeServlet] in context with path [/CaseStudy] threw exception
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at com.ntt.web.EmployeeServlet.showEditForm(EmployeeServlet.java:130)
    at com.ntt.web.EmployeeServlet.doGet(EmployeeServlet.java:75)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:543)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:615)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:818)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1627)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

EmployeeServlet.java

```
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String action=request.getServletPath();

        switch(action) {
        case "/new":
            showNewForm(request,response);
            break;

        case "/insert":

            try {
                insertUser(request,response);
            } catch (ServletException | IOException | SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            break;
        case "/delete":
            try {
                deleteUser(request,response);
            } catch (ServletException | IOException | SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        case "/edit":

            try {
                showEditForm(request,response);
            } catch (ServletException | IOException | SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;

        case "/update":
            try {
                updateUser(request,response);
            } catch (ServletException | IOException | SQLException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            break;
            default:
            try {
                listEmployee(request,response);
            } catch (ServletException | IOException | SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
                break;
        }

    }

    private void listEmployee(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException,IOException, SQLException{
        List<Employee> listEmployee=employeeDAO.selectAllEmployees();
        request.setAttribute("listEmployee",listEmployee);
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher=request.getRequestDispatcher("employee-list.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request,response);
    }

    private void deleteUser(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException,IOException, SQLException{
        int id=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
        employeeDAO.deleteEmployee(id);
        response.sendRedirect("list");
    }
    private void updateUser(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException,IOException, SQLException{
        int id=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id")); **errorline on which it shows error**
        String employeename=request.getParameter("employeename");
        String address=request.getParameter("address");
        String dateofjoining=request.getParameter("dateofjoining");
        String experience=request.getParameter("experience");
        String dateofbirth=request.getParameter("dateofbirth");

        Employee employee=new Employee(id,employeename,address,dateofjoining,experience,dateofbirth); 
        employeeDAO.updateEmployee(employee);
        response.sendRedirect("list");

    }

    private void showEditForm(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException,IOException, SQLException{
        int id=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
        Employee existingEmployee=employeeDAO.selectEmployee(id);
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher=request.getRequestDispatcher("employee-form.jsp");
        request.setAttribute("employee",existingEmployee);
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }
```

And also when i am inserting the data into the table it gets inserted there but i am not able to see the inserted data into my ui.And whem i try to click the edit or delete button on ui to edit or delete the data from table it shows error.

Comment: The exception should point you to the cause: `NumberFormatException: For input string: ""`

Comment: does `request.getParameter("id")` have any vaue or not ? can you post your html ?